# kubectl config set-credentials --auth-provider: Error: Unknown flag: --auth-provider

Tags: windows, kubernetes, openid-connect, kubectl

I've installed kubectl (version 1.16.0) on Windows 10, and the command works fine.

However, when tryin to run `kubectl config set-credentials <some_param> --auth-provider=oidc`, I get the following error: `Error: unknown flag: --auth-provider`.

This happens even though when I run `kubectl config set-credentials -h` I can see the `--auth-provider` as a possible option..

How can it be fixed?

Comment: Did you checked the correct syntax and options.kubectl config set-credentials USER_NAME --auth-provider=oidc --auth-provider-arg=idp-issuer-url=( issuer url ) --auth-provider-arg=client-id=( your client id ) \
  --auth-provider-arg=client-secret=( your client secret ) \
   --auth-provider-arg=refresh-token=( your refresh token ) \
   --auth-provider-arg=idp-certificate-authority=( path to your ca certificate ) \
   --auth-provider-arg=id-token=( your id_token ) \
   --auth-provider-arg=extra-scopes=( comma separated list of scopes to add to "openid email profile", optional )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use the kubectl [oidc](https://openid.net/connect/) authenticator during authentication process, which sets the id_token as a bearer token for all requests and refreshes the token once it expires. After you’ve logged into your provider, use kubectl to add your id_token, refresh_token, client_id, and client_secret to configure the plugin.

Proper configuration of command `kubectl config set-credentials` is that:

First you have to define user name for whom credentials will be created. Then you can pass additional parameters (enable oidc as auth-provider and add arguments to it). This is how proper syntax of `kubectl config set-credentials` command should look like:

```
   $ kubectl config set-credentials USER_NAME \
       --auth-provider=oidc \
       --auth-provider-arg=idp-issuer-url=( issuer url ) \
       --auth-provider-arg=client-id=( your client id ) \
       --auth-provider-arg=client-secret=( your client secret ) \
       --auth-provider-arg=refresh-token=( your refresh token ) \
       --auth-provider-arg=idp-certificate-authority=( path to your ca certificate ) \
       --auth-provider-arg=id-token=( your id_token )
```

More information about authentication you can find here: [kubernetes-authentication](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/access-authn-authz/authentication/).